# how to search loosely with SQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli

So i am trying to implement a search function using PHP and MySQL, i came across the `LIKE` SQL Operator, which works fine for basic string matching, but its looking for the exact match. i wondering how to be able to search loosely with MySQL.

Right now if you search with my search function, for **"blue jacket"**, then it will not match it with **"a very nice blue colored item | jacket"**. i want to be able to match that, any suggestions ?

My current MySQLi code for search, looks like this:

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM `items` where title LIKE CONCAT('%', ?, '%')");
```

Comment: You are looking for full text search.  Start with the documentation:  https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/fulltext-search.html.

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/fulltext-search.html

Comment: thnx it worked !

Answer (score 1):

after @Gordon Linoff and @Sammitch suggested the full text search, i went into phpmyadmin and marked `title` colum as full text, and then modified the SQL query to :

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM `items` WHERE MATCH(title) AGAINST ( ? IN NATURAL LANGUAGE MODE)");
```

For more info: dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/fulltext-search.html